# Make menu items fill height of action bar

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have an app with an action bar. **I need the menu items to fill the height of the action bar**. I have tried styling the action bar with `android:padding="0dp"` and settings `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` on the action views to no avail.

This picture shows that the browse subjects actionview for instance does not fill the actionbar.

[image]

Here is a shortened version of my menu declaration.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_more"
          android:title="More"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:actionProviderClass="pacakge.action_providers.MoreProvider"
            />
</menu>
```

The action provider class inflates and returns a view that is inserted into the ActionBar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up just hard coding the button height to 50dp. Not a very elegant solution but it works.

Comment: it's not the same for all configurations. better use @dimen/abs__action_bar_default_height instead.

Comment: where did you do the hard coding? i am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm....looks like you need to use bigger icons.

Also, in the layout for the buttons, use android:layout_height as "fill_parent".

And as a last tip, use android:showAsAction="ifRoom"

Answer (score 0):

Try to change menu item layout to RelavtiveLayout